# How can I run ElectronJS app on iPhone Simulator on a Mac?

Tags: ios, electron, ios-simulator

I'm planning on [working through the guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide) to deploy my ElectronJS app to the app store.

However, I'd like to test my app on a iPhone first and I have a Mac, Xcode and iPhone Simulators available.

**ElectronJS App On Simulator?**

I'd like to know the steps to run my Electron app on the simulator so I can test it.

I have googled but not found anything, [except this (related to Swift app)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device).

I know how to run a normal Swift app from Xcode in a Simulator, but I'm unsure how to run the Electron app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem that it is possible at this time to run an Electron App on an iPhone or iPad device ( and in turn not on a simulator either).

I didn't notice until after I posted my question, but [the Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide) seems to be for the **Mac** App Store, not the App Store (for iphones and ipads).